# Split GROUP_CONCAT result into separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This query:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT (CONVERT(SaleYear, CHAR(8)))
    ORDER BY
        SaleYear ASC
) AS SaleYears
FROM
    tblsales
WHERE
    Municipality = 'Oakville';
```

Produces this result:

```
1980,1981,1983,1985,1986,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013
```

All of the values are contained in the same column. What do I need to do if I want each value to be in a separate column?

Comment: Why do you want them in separate columns? How (by which name) would you access those columns? Why can't you just select them as rows? (i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT(SaleYear) FROM tblsales WHERE Municipality = 'Oakville'`)

Comment: Why do you want to have them in separate columns?

Comment: Hmmm, not really sure why I need them in separate columns.  I am trying to build a table that will display all the years in row1, and the corresponding vales in row 2.

Comment: So select the years plus corresponding values as rows and then use your frontend language (e.g. php) to format them horizontally in a table

Comment: @knittl - If I use `SELECT DISTINCT(SaleYear) FROM tblsales WHERE Municipality = 'Oakville'` it gives me the result in rows, but I want the result in columns.  That is why I am using GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Ok, that suggestion makes sense.  I'm using CodeIgniter, so will build the table with that.  Thanks.

Comment: HTML table rows != database rows. HTML table columns != database columns. Your DB does not care how your output format looks like and whether you display the rows as columns, as tiles, as separate pages, …

Comment: See: http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/

Comment: I want to do this as well, for creating a materialized view and taking advantage of column indexes on a large dataset. So all the "why do you want to do that, I'm so smart" narcissistic knee-jerk responses aside, does anyone actually know how to do this?